# “Clear Form” event from Facebook’s registration plugin?

Tags: facebook

I’m using Facebook’s Registration plugin `<fb:registration>` for new users to my site and, if they are logged in to Facebook, I display the plugin registration form. If the user selects the “close” button on the email portion of the form and then selects ”Log Out”, I get the logout event and remove the Facebook form and restore our own. If, however, the user selects the “Clear Form” button, it simply clears the Facebook form.

If the user isn’t going to connect her Facebook account, I’d prefer to display our  form when she presses ”Clear Form”.

Is there an event from the Facebook plugin that will tell me when the user selects “Clear Form”, or is there some other way I can achieve displaying the Facebook form only if the user is connecting her Facebook account?

There is an `fb_register` attribute that provides this basic functionality by removing the “Clear Form” button, but it also displays a message that says “you must use your Facebook account” to register, which is not true in our case.